# Pyplot - Drawing a log-log heat map under a curve

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I've been struggling with this problem for days, but haven't yet found an answer on the site, so here goes!

I've made a simple straight line plot made in python, using matplotlib.pyplot - It's essentially a triangle, bounded by two straight lines and the y-axis,  with a log-log scale. (I can upload the plot if this isn't a clear description, but I've not enough reputation to do so in this post - Sorry!)

The difficult part is, I now need to fill that triangle (and only that area ideally) with a heat map to show the values of a 3rd parameter, which depends on x and y in an extremely complex way. There's no simple function to describe z(x,y), but I have numerical tables giving the values of z at a range of discrete x and y values.

Is it at all possible to create such a graph (especially bearing in mind that the basic plot also has logarithmic axes)?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/dev/api/tri_api.html could help

Comment: Also look into [scipy.interpolate.griddata](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html). Anything more specific and you should post some code.

Comment: @Ajean, your solution of using interpolate.griddata sounds like it could work, and python had no issues with generating the interpolated grid when I tried it just then. Once I try to plot the map, though, terminal returns a warning that "Images are not supported on non-linear axes" and the plot itself looks like garbage. Is there any way to work around this to get the heat map to show on log-log axes? Thanks!

Comment: Provide a sample data and you might get a solution from SO

Comment: If you tried it, **post the code**. You can edit your question to include it.